# Format string vulnerability - stack organization for reading a random address

Tags: string, security, assembly, format, stack

I'm trying to understand how the format string vulnerabilities can work and how we can read any address.

I can check in real time how inputing "%x %x %x" in a printf will pop elements off the stack just above the string address.

This is how that stack looks once inside the printf:

```
(...)
0x7fffffffe018:    0x000000000040052c
0x7fffffffe020:    0x00007fffffffe180    
0x7fffffffe028:    0x00007fffffffe168
0x7fffffffe030:    *0x00007fffffffe48d* << address of argument   
0x7fffffffe038:    0x00007ffff7dd4e80 
0x7fffffffe040:    0x00007ffff7de9d60    
0x7fffffffe048:    0x00007ffff7ffe268
0x7fffffffe050:    0x0000000000000000    
0x7fffffffe058:    0x0000000000400563 <</ return address after printf
0x7fffffffe060:    0x00007fffffffe168    
0x7fffffffe068:    0x0000000200400440
(...)
```

and **0x7fffffffe48d** is the adress of the *"%x %x %x"* string further away in memory:

```
0x7fffffffe469:    "/home/.../C/format_string/test"
*0x7fffffffe48d*:    "%x %x %x"
0x7fffffffe4ac:    "SSH_AGENT_PID=..."
```

So logically this will output the 3 elements on top of this, ie:

```
ffffe168 ffffe180 40052c
```

Now, what I don't understand is, if I put a random address in the parameter, say:
*"\x15\xff\x0A\x23 %x %x %x %x %s"*, why would that *"\x15\xff\x0A\x23"* be actually stored on the stack and read by the "%s" ?

From what i'm seeing above, only the adress of the whole string is put on the stack (**0x00007fffffffe48d**) but not the characters (and indeed the address i intend to read) themselves.

Said differently, whatever I put inside my string, I can only control the content of address:

```
0x7fffffffe48d:    "blablabla %x %x %x"
```

but not what's going popped from the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the code does not push the content of the string on the stack.
It merely pushes its address.
Using a buffer overflow technique here will not allow you to overwrite the return address.

Unfortunately you don't show the C code.

The following C code would put its string data on the stack and thus could be exploited.
The following example from: http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html

**Stack based string - exploitable**

```
void overrunmybuffer(char *str) {
   char buffer[16];           <<-- local fixed sized array, stored on the stack.

   //should have used `strncpy()`    
   strcpy(buffer,str);  <<-- strcpy will blindly push 256 bytes in a 16 byte buffer
}

void main() {
  char large_string[256];
  int i;

  for( i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    large_string[i] = 'A';

  overrunmybuffer(large_string);
}
```

**Heap based string - difficult to exploit**
In your code the function looks something like this:

```
void cannotoverrunstack(char *str) {
   char *buffer;       <<-- pointer to char, only the address is stored on stack
   buffer = malloc(16);  
   strcpy(buffer,str); <<-- some other data in the heap will be overwritten
                            but not the stack.
}
```

Note that the data overwrite on the heap may or may not trigger an access violation and may overwrite useful data.
Because of the random way data gets assigned in the heap this is much less useful then overwriting the stack.
The stack frame has a very predictable layout and is thus very manipulatable.

The proper solution to the buffer overrun problem is to never use `strcpy` but to only use `strncpy` like so:

**Save code for fixed sized buffers**

```
void cannotoverrunmybuffer(char *str) {
   char buffer[16];           <<-- local fixed sized array, stored on the stack.

   strncpy(buffer,str,sizeof(buffer)-1);  <<-- only copy first 15 bytes. 
   buffer[15] = 0;                       <<-- !!put terminating 0 in!
}
```

Do not forget to forcefully zero-terminate your string, or you'll end-up reading past the end of the string, leading to lossage. If you're working with Unicode strings you need to put two terminating 0's in.

Even better would be to use automatically expanding strings like those used in Java or Delphi (`System::OpenString` in C++). 
Buffer overruns are impossible with those because they will automatically scale from 0 to 2GB's.